# is a chip "in" a smartwatch or "on" a smartwatch?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

i am learning Stanford [cs230](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuyk1nLMhRm6WkyV2sFP81ENNnsnydcm_).

the professor is [saying](https://youtu.be/QzN4cSH71D0?t=467)

> yesterday's supercomputer is today's processor on your smartwatch

why the professor is using "on" instead of "in"?

intuitively, a chip is "inside" a computer, a smartwatch or a smartphone.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a chip is *on* a computer's motherboard or an electronic device's circuit board. That aside, it could also be *part of* a computer.

Answer (score 1):

It was just a middle-of-lecture slip. I’d guess that in his head were two phrases, something like:

> ...today’s processor on your wrist...

and:

> ...today’s processor in your smart watch...

Then those two got stuck in the door, fighting with each other trying to get out at the same time, so that what eventually made it to our ears was:

> ...today’s processor on your smart watch...

So, yeah: slip of the tongue; brain fart. A bit like when Mr Trump graced as with “covfefe” (except that Andrew Ng is a really smart dude, and...well...and then there’s Mr Trump...)

Answer (score 0):

I think "in" is the more common usage. But "on" could be used and would not be wrong. When applied to a smaller, flatter device, such as a smartwatch, "on" might seem more natural than when applied to a desktop computer.